# Could anyone provide me with the performance charts for Boeing KC-135R Stratotanker?

Tags: aircraft-performance, military, boeing, refueling

I am looking for the Long Range Cruise Maximum Operating Altitude performance against the weight of the plane, all engines operating. Would be grateful if someone could point me the way.

Comment: I could only find this, and it doesn't answer your question, it just says the info has to be calculated. https://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a3/publication/afman11-2kc-135v3/afman11-2kc-135v3.pdf